# Get the last goal triggered by the current visitor

Tags: xdb, personalization

Is there a way in c# to get the name of the last goal triggered by the current visitor?

A simple conceptual example:
Bob visitors the homepage and clicks on a button (triggering a goal called "my button click"
Bob then fills out a contact form (triggering a goal called "contact form submitted")

Is there a good way in my back-end code (given I know Bob is current looking at the site) to get the fact that Bob's last triggered goal was "contact form submitted"?

I figure if that's not possible, I might be able to store a custom field against the visitor when the goal is triggered - but that seems unnecessary as the information should already be in the Mongo DB?

Solution is on Sitecore 7.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the tracker api to retrieve the latest Page Event:

```
    Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.SelectMany(x=>x.PageEvents)
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
```

*This is not tested code, let me know whether it works for you.*

**Update:**

If you want to get only goals, they can be filtered by adding this LINQ condition:

`.Where(x => x.IsGoal)`

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I had to make a small change to filter out only the Goals. I'm also worried that a session where the user visits loads of pages will make this inefficient - considering using a different approach but will keep this as a fallback :)
var latestGoal = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.
     SelectMany(x => x.PageEvents).Where(x => x.IsGoal).OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @OwenNiblock :) 
i have added the goals condition to the initial answer